# Display the lambda used in caret::BoxCoxTrans function

Tags: r, statistics, r-caret

I'm using `BoxCoxTrans` function from the `caret` package:

```
library(caret)
library(purrr)
model1 <- apply(X = my.df, 2, BoxCoxTrans)
model2 <- purrr::map2(model1, my.df, function(x,y) predict(x,y))
trans.df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, model2))

library(rcompanion)
plotNormalHistogram(trans.df)
print(trans.df)
```

It is working correctly and transforming the data, but I have no way of knowing which lambda value is used for the transformation.

Answer (score 2):

You can find these values in `model1`. I'll show you how to get them using the `iris` data.

```
library(caret)
fudge <- 0.2
out <- lapply(iris[1:2], BoxCoxTrans, fudge = fudge) # instead of apply(..., margin = 2, ...)
```

Now look at the structure of `out`

```
str(out, 2)
#List of 2
# $ Sepal.Length:List of 6
#  ..$ lambda  : num -0.1
#  ..$ fudge   : num 0.2
#  ..$ n       : int 150
#  ..$ summary :Classes 'summaryDefault', 'table'  Named num [1:6] 4.3 5.1 5.8 5.84 6.4 ...
#  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "Min." "1st Qu." "Median" "Mean" ...
#  ..$ ratio   : num 1.84
#  ..$ skewness: num 0.309
#  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "BoxCoxTrans"
# $ Sepal.Width :List of 6
#  ..$ lambda  : num 0.3
#  ..$ fudge   : num 0.2
#  ..$ n       : int 150
#  ..$ summary :Classes 'summaryDefault', 'table'  Named num [1:6] 2 2.8 3 3.06 3.3 ...
#  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "Min." "1st Qu." "Median" "Mean" ...
#  ..$ ratio   : num 2.2
#  ..$ skewness: num 0.313
#  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "BoxCoxTrans"
```

Using `base R` you can use `sapply` and `` `[[` `` now as follows

```
sapply(out, `[[`, "lambda")
#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width 
#        -0.1          0.3
```

Since you use `purrr`, you might consider `map` and `pluck`

```
map_dbl(out, pluck, "lambda")
#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width 
#        -0.1          0.3
```

---

Thanks to @missuse's mindful comments we can get the lambda used for transformation as

```
library(dplyr)
real_lambda <- case_when(between(lambda, -fudge, fudge) ~ 0,
                         between(lambda, 1 - fudge, 1 + fudge) ~ 1,
                         TRUE ~ lambda)

real_lambda <- setNames(real_lambda, names(lambda))
real_lambda
#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width 
#         0.0          0.3
```

This is necessary because the function `BoxCoxTrans` has the argument `fudge` which is

> a tolerance value: lambda values within +/-fudge will be coerced to 0 and within 1+/-fudge will be coerced to 1.

Comment: The `fudge` influences the lambda used for transformation, this is not accounted for when you just list the `lambda` value.

Comment: @missuse good point. Thought the question was about getting the `lambda` values only. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I trust Michael is interested in getting the lambda used for transformation, and this is not the lambda reported for all cases. For instance in your example `Sepal.Length` has a lambda `-0.1` but due to the fudge (default = 0.2) 0 is used. You can check that if you do `out$Sepal.Length` #output: `With fudge factor, Lambda = 0 will be used for transformations`. I have an idea how to calculate it but its not pretty and is not really suited for a comment.

Comment: Basically you need to check if the `lambda` falls within the range `0-fudge`, `0+fudge` then it will be `0`, and if its in the range `1-fudge`, `1+fudge` then it will be `1`.